# Can someone help me with the xpath syntax to get a paragraph from HTML

Tags: android, html, xpath

I am studying Software Development and doing Android and now I have a project where I have to get data from HTML and display it in my application.

The html im working with looks more or less like this:

`< PR >This paragraph contains a < B >bold < /B > word< /PR >.`

I need to extract the string as "This paragraph contains a bold word."

Ive tried `//p, /html/body/p, //p[@*]` and many more.

The paragraph also doesn't have a `div` or `id` for me to use `//div/p`.

I am new to this, Ive done XPath in my 2nd year but only briefly.

A working example was `//div[@id:blog-stats-2]/ul/li/` where I had to get the current views 
from a guys blog website, which worked.

I really need help. I will show you my code if it will make my question more clear.

Thanks in advance.

**Got the answer**

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();

            URL url = new URL(option_url);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            TagNode node = cleaner.clean(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            Object[] info_nodes = node.evaluateXPath("//P");

            if (info_nodes.length > 0) 
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < info_nodes.length; x++) 
                {
                    TagNode info_node = (TagNode) info_nodes[x];
                    String name = info_node.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("P NODES",name);
                }
            }
```

Now Im just going to save it in an array!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are using <pr>, which should be <p>. Is this a typo? Searching for p when there is a pr won't work.

Comment: And all that whitespace around the tag names -- if this is in your source document, you will pretty much get large problems with parsing it as HTML/XML as it isn't.

Comment: I just put the spaces there for you to see the tags otherwise it formatted to the string with a bold word.

Comment: Theres alot of big paragraphs < PR > text < BR > text < /BR > text < /PR >. I made a typo. Im really new to this and its also the first time I ask questions on here. Please help if you can. A link to the source code if that helps: view-source:http://www.guide-southafrica.za.net/emergency-hospital-and-rescue-numbers-in-south-africa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the expression `EXP` selects the paragraph you are interested in, then `string(EXP)` returns the string value of the paragraph, which is what you are after.

You haven't really given any clues as to what EXP might be, that is, how you want to distinguish this paragraph from all the others in the document.

Comment: We don't want a whole website. Extract enough, and no more, to explain the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the axes xpath, for example:
`//p/descendant-or-self::text()`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30772368)